# Installing Oracle 11gR2 on RHEL 6.2

Tags: installation, vmware, redhat-enterprise-linux, oracle-11g

I'm having some difficulty installing Oracle 11gR2 on RHEL 6.2.

I have compiled a giant list of every single step I have taken so far. I installed RHEL 6.2 on VMware. It did its easy install automatically.

- I selected 4GB of memory
- Selected max size of 80GB
- Selected two processors

The version of oracle I downloaded is Linux x86-64 11.2.0.1.

**I am installing this on a local machine NOT a remote machine**

I followed this documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24326/toc.htm

**I bolded the steps which I was least sure about from my research:**

1. Easy installed with RHEL 6.2 for VMware
2. Registered with Red Hat so I can get updates
3. Reinstalled vmware-tools by pressing enter at every choice
4. `sudo yum update` at the end - something about GPG key, selected y then y
5. Checked memory requirements:

   ```
   grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo
       MemTotal: 3921368 kb

   uname -m
       x86_64

   grep SwapTotal /proc/meminfo
       SwapTotal: 6160376 kb

   free
                    total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
       Mem:       3921368    2032012    1889356          0      76216    1533268
       -/+ buffers/cache:     422528    3498840
       Swap:      6160376          0    6160376

   df -h /dev/shm
       Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
       tmpfs                 1.9G  276K  1.9G   1% /dev/shm

   df -h /tmp
       Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
       /dev/sda2              73G  2.7G   67G   4% /


   df -h
       Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
       /dev/sda2              73G  2.7G   67G   4% /
       tmpfs                 1.9G  276K  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
       /dev/sda1             291M   58M  219M  21% /boot
   ```

   **All looked fine to me except maybe for swap?**
6. Software requirements:

   ```
   cat /proc/version
       Linux version 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-004.build.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.4.5 20110214 (Red Hat 4.4.5-6) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Nov 9 08:03:13 EST 2011

   uname -r
       2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64
   ```

   (same as above but whatever)

   According to the tutorial should be on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6, 2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64 or later.
7. These are the versions of software I have installed:

   ```
   binutils-2.20.51.0.2-5.28.el6.x86_64
   compat-libcap1-1.10-1.x86_64
   compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69.el6.x86_64
   compat-libstdc++-33.i686 0:3.2.3-69.el6
   gcc-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64
   gcc-c++.x86_64 0:4.4.6-3.el6
   glibc-2.12-1.47.el6_2.12.x86_64
   glibc-2.12-1.47.el6_2.12.i686
   glibc-devel-2.12-1.47.el6_2.12.x86_64
   glibc-devel.i686 0:2.12-1.47.el6_2.12
   ksh.x86_64 0:20100621-12.el6_2.1
   libgcc-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64
   libgcc-4.4.6-3.el6.i686
   libstdc++-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64
   libstdc++.i686 0:4.4.6-3.el6
   libstdc++-devel.i686 0:4.4.6-3.el6
   libstdc++-devel-4.4.6-3.el6.x86_64
   libaio-0.3.107-10.el6.x86_64
   libaio-0.3.107-10.el6.i686
   libaio-devel-0.3.107-10.el6.x86_64
   libaio-devel-0.3.107-10.el6.i686
   make-3.81-19.el6.x86_64
   sysstat-9.0.4-18.el6.x86_64

   unixODBC-2.2.14-11.el6.x86_64 
   unixODBC-devel-2.2.14-11.el6.x86_64
   unixODBC-devel-2.2.14-11.el6.i686
   unixODBC-2.2.14-11.el6.i686
   ```
8. Probably screwed up here or step 9:

   ```
   /usr/sbin/groupadd oinstall
   /usr/sbin/groupadd dba (not sure why this isn't in the tutorial)
   /usr/sbin/useradd -g oinstall -G dba oracle
   passwd oracle

   /sbin/sysctl -a | grep sem
   Xkernel.sem = 250   32000   32  128

   /sbin/sysctl -a | grep shm
   kernel.shmmax = 68719476736
   kernel.shmall = 4294967296
   kernel.shmmni = 4096
   vm.hugetlb_shm_group = 0

   /sbin/sysctl -a | grep file-max
   Xfs.file-max = 384629

   /sbin/sysctl -a | grep ip_local_port_range
   Xnet.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 32768   61000

   /sbin/sysctl -a | grep rmem_default
   Xnet.core.rmem_default = 124928

   /sbin/sysctl -a | grep rmem_max
   Xnet.core.rmem_max = 131071

   /sbin/sysctl -a | grep wmem_max
   Xnet.core.wmem_max = 131071

   /sbin/sysctl -a | grep wmem_default
   Xnet.core.wmem_default = 124928
   ```

   Here is my sysctl.conf file I only added the items that were bigger:

   ```
   # Kernel sysctl configuration file for Red Hat Linux
   #
   # For binary values, 0 is disabled, 1 is enabled.  See sysctl(8) and
   # sysctl.conf(5) for more details.

   # Controls IP packet forwarding
   net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0

   # Controls source route verification
   net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1

   # Do not accept source routing
   net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0

   # Controls the System Request debugging functionality of the kernel
   kernel.sysrq = 0

   # Controls whether core dumps will append the PID to the core filename.
   # Useful for debugging multi-threaded applications.
   kernel.core_uses_pid = 1

   # Controls the use of TCP syncookies
   net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1

   # Disable netfilter on bridges.
   net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
   net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
   net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0

   # Controls the maximum size of a message, in bytes
   kernel.msgmnb = 65536

   # Controls the default maxmimum size of a mesage queue
   kernel.msgmax = 65536

   # Controls the maximum shared segment size, in bytes
   kernel.shmmax = 68719476736

   # Controls the maximum number of shared memory segments, in pages
   kernel.shmall = 4294967296

   fs.aio-max-nr = 1048576
   fs.file-max = 6815744
   kernel.sem = 250 32000 100 128
   net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 9000 65500
   net.core.rmem_default = 262144
   net.core.rmem_max = 4194304
   net.core.wmem_default = 262144
   net.core.wmem_max = 1048576

   /sbin/sysctl -p
   net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
   net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
   net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0
   kernel.sysrq = 0
   kernel.core_uses_pid = 1
   net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
   error: "net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables" is an unknown key
   error: "net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables" is an unknown key
   error: "net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables" is an unknown key
   kernel.msgmnb = 65536
   kernel.msgmax = 65536
   kernel.shmmax = 68719476736
   kernel.shmall = 4294967296
   fs.aio-max-nr = 1048576
   fs.file-max = 6815744
   kernel.sem = 250 32000 100 128
   net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 9000 65500
   net.core.rmem_default = 262144
   net.core.rmem_max = 4194304
   net.core.wmem_default = 262144
   net.core.wmem_max = 1048576
   ```

   su - oracle

   ```
   ulimit -Sn
   1024
   ulimit -Hn
   1024
   ulimit -Su
   1024
   ulimit -Hu
   30482
   ulimit -Su
   1024
   ulimit -Ss
   10240
   ulimit -Hs
   unlimited
   ```

   su -

   ```
   nano /etc/security/limits.conf
   ```

   (added to the end of the file):

   ```
   oracle              soft    nproc   2047
   oracle              hard    nproc   16384
   oracle              soft    nofile  1024
   oracle              hard    nofile  65536
   oracle              soft    stack   10240

   exit
   exit
   su -

   mkdir -p /app/
   chown -R oracle:oinstall /app/
   chmod -R 775 /app/
   ```
9. THIS IS PROBABLY WHERE I MESSED UP

   I then exited out of the root account so now I'm back in my account chris then I:

   ```
   su - oracle

   echo $SHELL
   /bin/bash

   umask
   0022 (so it should be set already to what is necessary)
   ```

   Also from what I have read I do not need to set the DISPLAY variable because I'm installing this on the localhost.

   I then opened the .bash_profile of Oracle and changed it to the following:

   ```
   # .bash_profile

   # Get the aliases and functions
   if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
           . ~/.bashrc
   fi
   ```

**User specific environment and startup programs:**

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin; export PATH
ORACLE_BASE=/app/oracle
ORACLE_SID=orcl
export ORACLE_BASE ORACLE_SID
```

I then shutdown the virtual machine shared my desktop folder from my Windows 7 then turned back on the virtual machine logged in as chris opened up a terminal then:

```
su -
```

For some reason the shared folder didn't appear so I reinstalled VMware Tools again and restarted, then the same as before:

```
su - 

cp -R linux_oracle/database /db; chown -R oracle:oinstall /db; chmod -R 775 /db; ll /db
drwxrwxr-x. 8 oracle oinstall 4096 Jun  5 06:20 database

exit
su - oracle
cd /db/database
./runInstaller
```

**FINALLY THE INFAMOUS JAVA:132 ERROR MESSAGE:**

```
Starting Oracle Universal Installer...

Checking Temp space: must be greater than 80 MB.   Actual 65646 MB    Passed
Checking swap space: must be greater than 150 MB.   Actual 6015 MB    Passed
Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors.    Actual 16777216    Passed
Preparing to launch Oracle Universal Installer from /tmp/OraInstall2012-06-05_06-47-12AM. Please wait ...[oracle@localhost database]$ Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/OraInstall2012-06-05_06-47-12AM/jdk/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so: libXext.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1751)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1647)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:769)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:968)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1751)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1668)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:822)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:993)
    at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:50)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1509)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1530)
    at com.jgoodies.looks.LookUtils.isLowResolution(Unknown Source)
    at com.jgoodies.looks.LookUtils.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.jgoodies.looks.plastic.PlasticLookAndFeel.<clinit>(PlasticLookAndFeel.java:122)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:242)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.loadSystemClass(SwingUtilities.java:1783)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:480)
    at oracle.install.commons.util.Application.startup(Application.java:758)
    at oracle.install.commons.flow.FlowApplication.startup(FlowApplication.java:164)
    at oracle.install.commons.flow.FlowApplication.startup(FlowApplication.java:181)
    at oracle.install.commons.base.driver.common.Installer.startup(Installer.java:265)
    at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBInstaller.startup(DBInstaller.java:114)
    **at oracle.install.ivw.db.driver.DBInstaller.main(DBInstaller.java:132)
```

Comment: In the future pease format your question so it can be read more easily.

Answer (score 1):

When you run into these kind of problem `yum whatprovides` is the answer:

```
$ sudo yum whatprovides libXext.so.6
Loaded plugins: protect-packages, protectbase, rhnplugin, security
0 packages excluded due to repository protections
libXext-1.0.1-2.1.i386 : X.Org X11 libXext runtime library
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-5
Matched from:
Other       : libXext.so.6



libXext-1.0.1-2.1.i386 : X.Org X11 libXext runtime library
Repo        : installed
Matched from:
Other       : Provides-match: libXext.so.6
```

So you need to install libXext.

Answer (score 0):

Have you started installation from root or oracle user? I think it is display related error... and if you will logout from root and login with oracle user and then trying to install may resolve this error.

Please don't do su - oracle, totally logout from root and login as a oracle user. error will be resolved.